# news.reads php sdk on facebook - cant publish

Tags: php, facebook

I'm trying to publish an action via news.reads action, but I got stuck.

after sending $facebook->api - it likes throw me an "exit" like, no response after this line.

the code:

```
    <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ob_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="he-IL">
    <head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# 
                  article: http://ogp.me/ns/article#">
     <meta property="og:type" content="article" /> 
  <meta property="fb:app_id" content="306597542762982" /> 
  <meta property="og:url"    content="http://v2.raal.co.il/index.php" /> 
  <meta property="og:title"  content="הצצה נדירה: יחידת אגוז, קומנדו היבשה של צהל" /> 
  <meta property="og:description" content="יחידת אגוז התאמנה השבוע באחד המתארים הקשים ביותר, מתאר ה..." /> 

     <meta property="og:site_name"            content="פורטל רעל">

     <meta property="article:published_time"  content="DateTime"> 
     <meta property="article:modified_time"   content="DateTime"> 
     <meta property="article:expiration_time" content="DateTime">
     <meta property="article:author"          content="URL to Author object">
     <meta property="article:section"         content="Section of article">
     <meta property="article:tag"             content="Keyword">
 </head>

    <body>


<?Php
//uses the PHP SDK.  Download from https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk
require 'src/facebook.php';


$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '306597542762982',
  'secret' => '88XX7f1',
));


$user = $facebook->getUser();
if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}

if (!$user) {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
  header("Location: " . $loginUrl);
}
    //echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$url';</script>";




$params = array (
  'article' => 'http://v2.raal.co.il/',
  'access_token' => $facebook->getAccessToken()
);



$out = $facebook->api( '/me/news.reads','post', $params);
var_dump($out);


   ?>

  </body>
</html>
```

I get in response : 1 2 (print 1; print 2;)

while print_r($out) returns me null.

Comment: Where are you setting a value for `$out` ?

Comment: $out = $facebook->api('/me/news.reads', 'post', $params);  accedently removed it when i uploaded the code to here

Comment: is 'artice' in your code copied verbatim? it should be 'article'

Comment: fixed, still get no response from $out. even stranger, if i put "print 3;" after the link ($facebook->api), it wont print it. like the code get stuck on this line. something in the api itself maybe?

Comment: Is your server unable to make the outbound call? does your browsers web developer tools / proxy logs / server logs show the request going out?

Comment: I've checked on firebug , no request going out..

Comment: Wich call seems no work ?
$facebook->api('/me'), $facebook->api( '/me/news.reads','post', $params) or both don't work?
Can tou post the log please.

Answer (score 4):

First: Article is misspelled (artice), did you check that ?

Second: The url you are trying to publish is not an article, you have to add the og:tags in it, look at [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/objects/builtin/#article).

Third: Do you have publish_stream permissions ?

Can you check the output using [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=100002076768728?fields=id,name)?

Comment: Well, i fixed the tags, the article misspelling, permissions, now i get:

Comment: [30-Sep-2012 09:17:39] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.
  thrown in /home1/raalcoil/public_html/v2/base_facebook.php on line 1106
[30-Sep-2012 09:17:39] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught OAuthException: (#3502) Object at URL http://v2.raal.co.il/ has og:type of 'website'. The property 'article' requires an object of og:type 'article'. 
  thrown in /home1/raalcoil/public_html/v2/base_facebook.php on line 1106

Comment: You did not fixed the tags, take a loot at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.raal.co.il%2Fv2%2Findex2.php
And fix it first

Comment: In fact the article url is returning an 404 error code, you need to fix it!

Comment: the above comment is the right link, i cant figure out why it gives me 500 error code..

Comment: Try to display all erros and warnings : http://www.phpreferencebook.com/tips/display-all-php-errors-and-warnings/

Comment: Ok i did it, now for some reason i get endless loop in the loging proccess. (P.s ive updated the code on the question)